# How to use visual studio 2008 as an IDE for Qt?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

I want to use visual studio 2008 as an IDE for Qt programming to be able to drag and drop push buttons, combos, etc. 
On the form I'm designing rather than generating those widgets using code.

How to do this?

thanks